# Unconditional WAIT statement's effect on processes in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

There is something I do not understand about VHDL processes ending with an unconditional `wait` statement. To illustrate my problem, I need to compare the 2 following snipets :

snipet 1 :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture sim of foo is
  signal clk : std_logic := '0';
  signal s   : std_logic;

begin
  clk <= not clk after 10 ns;

  -- driver1
  s <= '0';

  -- driver2
  process (clk) is
  begin
    s <= clk;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

There is a double assignment for signal s: Driver1 drives the signal s to '0' while driver2 alternatively drives it to '0' and '1'. As we can see on the waveform graph, when clk is '0', the resulting s is '0' (green segments) but when clk is '1', the resulting s is 'X' (red segments).
[image]
=> I understand this behaviour, no problem with that one.

If I modify slightly this code by changing driver1 into a process ended with an unconditional `wait` instruction :

snipet2 :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture sim of foo is
  signal clk : std_logic := '0';
  signal s   : std_logic;

begin
  clk <= not clk after 10 ns;

  -- driver1
  -- s <= '0';
  process 
  begin
    s <= '0';
    wait;
  end process;

  -- driver2
  process (clk) is
  begin
    s <= clk;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Surprisingly, for me, the snipet 2 produces the same waveform as the snipet 1. My understanding is that the instructions inside a process with a final "unconditional" `wait` statement will stop forever, meaning that their code will be inactive after the first execution run. But if this is truly the case, I would expect that driver1 in snipet 2 is inactive after its first run, and that from that point driver2 remains the only active driver of signal s, always assigning clk's alternative '1's and '0's to it.

Why isn't it the case?

Comment: You seem to be conflating quiet (not active) and disconnected (not driven).

Comment: @user1155120. Thanks, so the `wait` statement makes the process execution stop after the first iteration, but keeps the signals (signal s here) "connected" and driven to their current value for the rest of the execution?

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a signal in a process, a driver is created for that signal from the moment it assigned until the end of simulation. So here, both code snippets are functionally equivalent, you create driver1 from time 0 and driver2 from the first clock.

Comment: To be pedantic, when you assign a signal in a process, a driver is created _during elaboration_ until the end of simulation. Until a line of code containing a signal assignment is executed, the default value for the type is driven on the signal (`'U'` in this case). When the line of code containing the signal assignment is executed, then whatever value is assigned is driven until another line of code (or the same one) with an assignment to the same signal is executed. In this case, that's a `'0'`, which is driven until the end of the simulation.